# How do I include strikethrough text in geom_text_repel or geom_text labels for ggplot?

Tags: r, text, ggplot2, ggrepel

Is it possible to add <del>strikethrough</del> to some `geom_text`/`geom_text_repel` labels?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41528953/how-do-i-include-italic-text-in-geom-text-repel-or-geom-text-labels-for-ggplot) question mentioned that you can *italicise* a label using the following:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("ggrepel")

df <- data.frame(
  x = c(1,2),
  y = c(2,4),
  lab = c("italic('Italic Text')", "Normal"))

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, label = lab)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_text_repel(parse = T)
```

[image]

However, I've been unable to use the same method to get strikethrough text.

```
df$lab = c("strike('Strikethrough Text')", "Normal")

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, label = lab)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_text_repel(parse = T)
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20315962/r-text-formatting-of-plot-label-text-strikethrough ?

Comment: That question is applying formatting to the axis, not the labels. If it is possible to use the same method on `geom_text_repel` labels, please let me know.

Comment: it is using `plotmath` and there is no `strike` command. have a look at `demo(plotmath)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using a Unicode long strike overlay?

[image]

```
R Script
# Long strikethru test
# Unicode Character 'COMBINING LONG STROKE OVERLAY' (U+0336)

library("tidyverse")

# Keep 30 first rows in the mtcars natively available dataset
data <- head(mtcars, 30)

name <- "Strikethrough"
name_strk <- str_replace_all(name, "(?<=.)", "\u0336")

# Add one annotation
ggplot(data, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) +
  geom_point() + # Show dots
  geom_label(
    label= name_strk,
    x=4.1,
    y=20,
    label.padding = unit(0.55, "lines"), # Rectangle size around label
    label.size = 0.35,
    color = "black",
    size = 4,
    fill="white"
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned in the comments, `plotmath` cannot handle strikethrough. However, we can do some tricks with `phantom` and `underline`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  y = c(1, 2),
  lab = c("italic('Italic Text')", "Strikethrough"),
  do_strike = c(FALSE, TRUE)
)
```

`wrap_strike` takes the text and wraps it in `phantom` which makes it invisible. For strikethrough text, it adds an `underline`.

```
wrap_strike <- function(text, do_strike) {
  text <- glue::glue("phantom({text})")
  ifelse(do_strike, glue::glue("underline({text})"), text)
}
```

If we nudge the `y` position of the new text, the underlines become strikethrough.

```
ggplot(df, aes(1, y, label = lab)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(parse = TRUE, hjust = 0) +
  geom_text(
    data = mutate(df, lab = wrap_strike(lab, do_strike)),
    parse = TRUE,
    hjust = 0,
    vjust = 0.1
  )
```

[image: strikethrough]